# how can I make a two pointer python script faster? (by using binary search)

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a **Leetcode** question that asks you to find all triplets that sum up to 0 in a given group.
Heres a link to the question https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/

I found a script online that was too slow, so I tried optimizing it with a binary search. however, it remained too slow.
Was my implementation of binary search wrong? or does the code just need more optimization?

the original code

```
def zeroSumTriplets(nums):
    result = set()
    for i,a in enumerate(nums[:-2],1):
        for j,b in enumerate(nums[i:-1],i+1):
            if -a-b not in nums[j:]: continue
            triplet = tuple(sorted([a,b,-a-b]))
            result.add(triplet)
    return list(result)
```

and the code after attempting to add binary search

```
class Solution(object):
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        nums.sort()
        result = set()
        for i,a in enumerate(nums[:-2],1):
            for j,b in enumerate(nums[i:-1],i+1):
                if a + b + nums[j + int(round((len(nums)-j)/2))] >= 0:
                    if -a-b not in nums[j:int(round((len(nums)-j)/2))]:continue
                    triplet = tuple(sorted([a,b,-a-b]))
                    result.add(triplet)

                if a + b + nums[j + int(round((len(nums)-j)/2))] < 0:
                    if -a-b not in nums[j+int(round((len(nums)-j)/2)):]:continue
                    triplet = tuple(sorted([a,b,-a-b]))
                    result.add(triplet)          
        return list(result)
```

Edit:
some people advised me to use a hashtable, however now the code doesn't return anything (**result** seems to be empty)for some reason and I wish to know why.

here is the new code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        hashtable = dict()
        result = set()
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            hashtable[i] = nums[i]
        print(hashtable)
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            a = nums[i]
            for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
                b = nums[j]
                try:
                    if hashtable[-(a+b)] > j:
                        triplet = tuple(sorted([a,b,-a-b]))
                        result.add(triplet)
                except:
                    continue
        return list(result)
```

Comment: I read about it online...
Do you have a good source I can learn from?

Comment: Both of these proposed solutions are O(n^3)

Comment: I think it's my fault. not the source

Comment: Where are you doing binary search here? I presume you refer to `i` and `j` as the two pointers. Binary search involves moving these pointers around in bigger steps, but you are still going in single steps linearly.

Comment: I see I didn't really understand binary search while making it, Ill try to relearn it and update the post

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a binary search, which is O(lg n), but rather a hash table, which is O(1).  I'm not going to write the code for you, because this is LeetCode and you're trying to learn to code.

But create a hashtable in which the keys are the elements of `nums`, and the value is the last index at which that element occurs in `nums`.  Then for each pair of elements nums[i] and num[j] (i < j), see if hashtable[-(nums[i] + nums[j])] exists and is > j.

Another thing slowing down your code.  Normally, I'm a big fan of enumerate, but calling nums[i:-1] makes a copy of your array, which is slow.

You just want:

```
   for i in range(len(nums)):
      a = nums[i]
      for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
          b = nums[j]
```

Comment: is this what you mean by making a hashtable?

`hashtable = dict()
        place = 0
        for i in nums:
            hastable[i] = place
            place = place + 1`

Comment: I tried rewriting the code using hashtable but I still can get it to work.
could you maybe have a look or give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Frank Yellin has elaborated on the better approach of using a hash map (and using ranges instead of slices, which copy). I'll show the slower binary search approach here. You can save yourself implementing the binary search by using Python's built-in [bisection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), specifically `bisect_left`. We can modify the given example of `index` to a `contains`:

```py
def contains(a, lo, x):
    i = bisect_left(a, x, lo=lo)
    return i != len(a) and a[i] == x
```

Note that we need the `lo` parameter to avoid slicing `a`.
That way, we can optimize `threeSum` from O(n³) to O(n² log n) time complexity by using the binary instead of a linear search in the innermost loop. We also have `a <= b <= -a-b` (if `-a-b` is contained in the slice of values larger than `b`), so there's no need to sort the triples anymore. To avoid duplicates, start by avoiding duplicate `a`s: Ignore `a`s equal to the last `a` you have already seen. Do the same for `b`s. This will guarantee uniqueness of your triples such that you can get rid of the `set` for the result and use a simple `list` instead (this is irrelevant for asymptotic time complexity, but may matter in practice). Overall, we obtain (omitting the Leetcode `class` cruft):

```py
def contains(a, lo, x):
    i = bisect_left(a, x, lo=lo)
    return i != len(a) and a[i] == x
def threeSum(nums):
    nums.sort() # sort the numbers to be able to use a binary search
    result = []
    last_a = None
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-2):
        a = nums[i]
        if a == last_a: continue
        last_a = a
        last_b = None
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)-1):
            b = nums[j]
            if b == last_b: continue
            last_b = b
            if contains(nums, j+1, -a-b):
                result.append([a, b, -a-b])
    return list(result)
```